# Accessing beans in portlet specific context programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I have a portlet application.  It is configured using Spring framework IoC container.  I am using org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener to load my context.

I have an application context at root level (applicationContext.xml) and a portlet specific context (MyPortlet-portlet.xml).

I have a portlet of type org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet which is wired up to a Controller.  In the Controller I want to access one of the beans (e.g. bean with id "myBean") I have defined in my portlet specific context.  I have tried

```
MyBean mybean = (MyBean)PortletApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
    getPortletContext()).getBean("myBean")
```

However only the beans in my application context are available here - none of my beans in my portlet specific context are available.

Is there a way to access the beans in my portlet specific context?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, can't you just wire in the bean to your controller in the normal way, rather than retrieving it programmatically?

Failing that, you should realise that [`getWebApplicationContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/context/PortletApplicationContextUtils.html#getWebApplicationContext%28javax.portlet.PortletContext%29) gets a reference to the root webapp context, not the servlet app context:

> Find the root WebApplicationContext
>   for this portlet application, which is
>   typically loaded via
>   ContextLoaderListener or
>   ContextLoaderServlet.

If your controller needs a handle on its own context, then it should implement `ApplicationContextAware` or `BeanFactoryAware`, or it can use `@Autowired ApplicationContext` if you want to use autowiring.

Comment: Hi, the reason I am not wiring my bean in the normal way is because the Controller has a Service which is a singleton, which needs a Processor which is not a singleton.  So I am getting the Processor in the Controller every time and passing it to the Service.  Is there a better way to configure this in the XML context file?

Comment: @Aos: Yes, I described the better way in the answer - use `ApplicationContextAware` etc

Comment: Okay - thank you for your help.  I have my controller working now.